# Custom taskbar icon when using chrome.app.window.create

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Is it possible to have an icon different then the one specified in the manifest when opening an app window with `chrome.app.window.create` ?

Basically I would like to be able to open multiple windows each having its own icon.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, no. It's challenging to provide a custom icon at all on every operating system, particularly OS X, so at the moment our goal is merely to let end users identify who owns a given window, and that means using the app icon for all the app's windows. If you have a specific use case that you believe would be meaningful across different operating systems, would you please describe it at [crbug.com](http://crbug.com) so that we can consider it in a future release? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is available as of Chrome M54.

An image URL can now be specified as an `icon` property within [CreateWindowOptions](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#type-CreateWindowOptions) when calling [chrome.app.window.create](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#method-create)